# Circular Shifting of words in a line of sentence in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am  writing a code to circular shift words in a sentence per line. Assume I input the following two lines:

- merry christmas brother
- happy new year sister

The output should be:

```
brother merry christmas
christmas brother merry
merry christmas brother

sister happy new year
year sister happy new
new year sister happy
happy new year sister
```

this is the code that i have written so far

```
function array_sort($array){
$new_array = array();
$sortable_array = array();

if (count($array) > 0) {
    foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
        if (is_array($v)) {
            foreach ($v as $k2 => $v2) {

                    $sortable_array[$k] = $v2;

            }
        } else {
            $sortable_array[$k] = $v;
        }
    }

    foreach ($sortable_array as $k => $v) {
        $new_array[$k] = $array[$k];
    }
}

return $new_array;
}


foreach($str_in as $str){
   $st= explode(" ",trim($str));
    //print_r($st);
for($i=0;$i<count($st);$i++){


  $sorted = array_sort($st);

}

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a lot easier with [`array_pop()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) and [`array_unshift()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php).

---

#### Example:

```
$strings = [
    "merry christmas brother",
    "happy new year sister"
];

foreach ($strings as $string) {
    $words = explode(" ", $string);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($words); $i++) {
        array_unshift($words, array_pop($words));
        echo implode(" ", $words), "\n";
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

---

#### Output:

```
brother merry christmas
christmas brother merry
merry christmas brother

sister happy new year
year sister happy new
new year sister happy
happy new year sister
```

Comment: this is what have been looking for, thanks @paul-crovella. any easy way to arrange the output aphabetically?